# How to repeat a remapped command thats starts with a leader key in VIM?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

i have made a macro that reformat a word that example `apple` to be `.apple(apple)` and i have saved that macro to be remapped with the `<leader>z` combination as follows
`nnoremap <leader>z 0yiwI.<esc>a(<esc>hpA),<esc>j0` the problem is when i type a number followed by `<leader>z` expecting the command to be repeated by the number i have given, it instead moves 10 lines downward i.e. it excutes the  part only how do i fix that behaviour where i enter the number of repetitions of the command i want and it excutes correctly
Note: I have the leader key remapped to space

Comment: For what it's worth, those are *mappings* not "remappings".

Comment: Store your macro in a register, say register z, and execute it 10 times with `10@z`.

Comment: I use the macro everyday and i thought it would be a nice addition to have a way to store it as to not do it again everytime i use VIM

Answer (score 3):

If you want to keep using that macro over and over again, the most effortless way is to assign it to a register in your `vimrc`:

```
let @z = "0yiwI.\<esc>a(\<esc>hpA),\<esc>j0"
```

and use it like this:

```
@z
10@z
```